Cant run project flutter with emulator
enter image description hereWho can help me fix this,i done add the adb but still cant
I cant run my project with emulator always like that,please help me to fix that,
I done add the adb in platform-tools but still cant to run the project,maybe who can help me to fix my problem,thank you

is this your answer ??

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Install NDK and other dependencies from sdk manager in android studio. It would look like this
Image

done install ndk but still cant run my emulator

check the screenshot, I have shared. Install all the dependencies that are tick or have (-) written. Everything will work after that

done install all sir but still cant
